# Junit won't assert true

Tags: java, postgresql, junit

After following the examples given attempted to create my own junit test however the thing keeps getting caught on  `assertTrue(rs.next());`

Code I'm trying to test

```
public void insertEmployee(Employees emp) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        final String SQL = "INSERT INTO " + '"' + "Remburstment"+ '"' + ".employee values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);

            ps.setString(1, emp.getEmail());
            ps.setString(2, emp.getPassword());
            ps.setString(3, emp.getFirstName());
            ps.setString(4, emp.getLastName());
            ps.setBoolean(5, emp.getIsAManager());
            ps.setString(6, emp.getMyManagerEmail());
            ps.setString(7, emp.getMyManagerFirstName());
            ps.setString(8, emp.getMyManagerLastName());
            ps.execute();

        }catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            ConnectionClosers.closeConnection(conn);
            ConnectionClosers.closeStatement(ps);
        }

        LOGGY.debug("The EmployeeRepository insertEmployee was successfully called, and it created: " + emp);
    }
```

The Junit test

```
        @Test
        public void TestInsertEmployee()
        {

            Connection conn= null;

            try
            {
                 conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
                try(Statement stCheck=conn.createStatement())
                {
                    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

                    // Initial cleanup:
                    stCheck.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM " +'"' + "Remburstment"+ '"' + ".manager");
                    stCheck.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM " + '"' + "Remburstment"+ '"' + ".employee");


                    // Setting input parameters
                    String userName = "employee";
                    String Password = "password1";
                    String firstName = "bob";
                    String lastName = "Kelco";
                    String myManagerEmail = "manger";
                    String myManagerFirstName = "Robert";
                    String myManagerLastName= "Cox";
                    Boolean isAManager = false;

                    // Do the call:
                    Manager manguy = new Manager(myManagerEmail, Password, myManagerFirstName, myManagerLastName );
                    Employees guy = new Employees(myManagerEmail, Password, myManagerFirstName, myManagerLastName, true, myManagerEmail, myManagerFirstName, myManagerLastName);
                    Employees emp = new Employees(userName, Password, firstName, lastName,isAManager, myManagerEmail, myManagerFirstName, myManagerLastName );
                    empRepository.insertManager(guy);
                    empRepository.insertEmployee(guy);
                    empRepository.insertEmployee(emp);

                    // Javabean Checks: Check the javabean contains the expected values:
                    assertEquals(userName, emp.getEmail());
                    assertEquals(firstName, emp.getFirstName());
                    assertEquals(Password, emp.getPassword());
                    assertEquals(lastName, emp.getLastName());
                    assertEquals(isAManager, emp.getIsAManager());
                    assertEquals(myManagerEmail, emp.getMyManagerEmail());
                    assertEquals(myManagerFirstName, emp.getMyManagerFirstName());
                    assertEquals(myManagerLastName, emp.getMyManagerLastName());

                    // Database Checks:

                    // Check the Person table contains one row with the expected values:
                    try(ResultSet rs=stCheck.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  " + '"' + "Remburstment"+ '"' + ".employee "))
                    {
                        //System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                       // assertTrue(rs.next());
                        rs.next();
                        System.out.println(rs);
                        assertEquals(userName, rs.getString(1));
                        assertEquals(firstName, emp.getFirstName());
                        assertEquals(Password, emp.getPassword());
                        assertEquals(lastName, emp.getLastName());
                        assertEquals(isAManager, emp.getIsAManager());
                        assertEquals(myManagerEmail, emp.getMyManagerEmail());
                        assertEquals(myManagerFirstName, emp.getMyManagerFirstName());
                        assertEquals(myManagerLastName, emp.getMyManagerLastName());
                        assertFalse(rs.next());
                    }

                    // Check the Contractor table contains one row with the expected values:

                    System.out.println(userName);
                    try(ResultSet rs=stCheck.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + '"' + "Remburstment"+ '"' + ".employee WHERE userName ="+ userName ))
                    {
                        assertTrue(rs.next());
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                        assertEquals(userName, rs.getString(1));
                        assertEquals(firstName, emp.getFirstName());
                        assertEquals(Password, emp.getPassword());
                        assertEquals(lastName, emp.getLastName());
                        assertEquals(isAManager, emp.getIsAManager());
                        assertEquals(myManagerEmail, emp.getMyManagerEmail());
                        assertEquals(myManagerFirstName, emp.getMyManagerFirstName());
                        assertEquals(myManagerLastName, emp.getMyManagerLastName());
                        assertFalse(rs.next());
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                     // Undo the testing operations:
                     conn.rollback();
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                fail(e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi. Are you sure there is no other exception? Last time I checked, running psql query with database name (eg. `Remburstment.employee`) caused exception. I needed to run it without database name (eg. `employee`)

Answer (score 0):

Few things need to be checked

- Have you annotated the class with MockitoJUnitRunner. Because this will start the application as real one so that the objects inside can be instantiated.
- This is Junit test? I haven't seen any Mocking happening here. Basically you ResulSet should actually be Mocked.
- I guess so, NPE is due to that your ConnectionFactory Given Connection Object which does not contain your DB connection values, so you get exception.

Always try to mock objects which handles Business logic.

Comment: Junit tests can perfectly exist without mockito. Why do you need to mock business logic if you want to test business logic?

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit transaction at some point or use the same connection for inserts g data and selecting it in your test method. Your insert method do insert and then closing connection without commit so no data will actually be written to the database.
You either need to call `connection.commit()` or allow autocommits.